# Call hierarchy analysis tool for Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am learning the Cloudfoundry code. Cloudfoundry is mainly written in Ruby, so now I would like to find a tool to generate the call hierarchy flow, so that I can easily understand the workflow, and function calls inside the platform. Can someone help to point it out? I have tried to find some project on Github, but none are working with the Cloudfoundry source code.

Comment: unanswered duplicate: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19126/94

Comment: @AngeloFuchs The duplicate has an answer now.