# Tools for creating call graph for Ruby application?

Tags: ruby, code-analysis, source-code

I am looking for tools that create call graph for Ruby applications, like this https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.org/en/master/

[image]

but unfortunately it's for Python.

Anything that could help me analyze unfamiliar code easily would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unanswered duplicate: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14355/94

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [stackprof](https://rubygems.org/gems/stackprof) gem will generate a call graph.  Its [readme](https://github.com/tmm1/stackprof/blob/master/README.md) shows this sample:

[image: call graph output from stackprof]